# Programming USB OTG PIC32 through USB in MPLAB

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, mplab, usb-otg

I have a PIC32 that has USB OTG. How would I program it through a USB cable in MPLAB? Does it work out of the box of does it need additional software.

Comment: @Bence Kaulics Why did you remove the thanks?

Comment: It was unnecessary. You should do a little research first, add what have you found and ask then.  You can express your gratitude by asking a good question. See [more](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: @Bence Kaulics I was just trying to be nice.

Comment: No problem there, but as it is not a forum, conversational terms are avoided in questions and answers.

Comment: You need to specify more details? Which PIC32? MPLAB 8 or X? Are you talking about a development kit or 'just a part' without any pre-programmed firmware? AFAIK Microchip does not blow any special firmware into their parts unless you pay them extra for it and provide the software yourself (they spin a custom part/order number for you for this activity).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to use one of a small number of 'approved' programmers from within MPLAB X to program a part:

- PICkit3
- ICD3
- REAL ICE
- PM3
- PKOB (see below)

Some development kits provide you a USB 'programming port' but if you study the schematic, you'll see that what you're interfacing with is the equivalent circuitry and firmware of a PICkit3 embedded on the board. This shows up as PKOB or 'PICkit on-board'.

I do USB work and I don't reprogram from within MPLAB X - I build my HEX file then switch over to my bootloader application to program the part. Assuming your device was USB-bootloadable you could modify the build process to call a bootloader program as a post-build step. (You would still need a bootloader, and an official programmer to get the bootloader into the part in the first place, but hey.)